# How to bypass the "Do you want to continue?" part when using apt in scripts

Tags: bash, shell-script, apt

Hello everyone? I am fairly new to Linux bash files. Overall, my experience is good with using the Debian distro versus fedora and RedHat.

I am writing a `bash` command for updating my Linux terminal. I am using Peppermint 10, an off-brand of Ubuntu Linux. I got the code working; however, I want to bypass

```
Do you want to continue? [Y/n]
```

Here is my code:

```
#!/bin/bash

        echo
        /bin/echo -e "\e[1;33m   !---------------------------------------------!\e[0m"
        /bin/echo -e "\e[1;33m   !   Installing Updates, Upgrades, and Dist-Upgrades Packages...Proceeding...  !\e[0m"
        /bin/echo -e "\e[1;33m   !---------------------------------------------!\e[0m"
        echo
        #installing updates, upgrades, and dist-upgrade
                sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade && sudo apt dist-upgrade -Y
```

I tried the `echo Y`, `-y`, and `-Y`, any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

You can use `sudo apt-get -y upgrade` to avoid the *yes/no* questions, but avoiding all questions is a little bit more tricky because sometimes `dpkg` asks for config files updates/overwrites etc.

To use `apt` fully non-interactive you'll need these `apt`/`dpkg` options:

```
DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive apt-get -y -o "Dpkg::Options::=--force-confdef" -o "Dpkg::Options::=--force-confold" upgrade
```

Answer (score 2):

Other ways to bypass `apt` question:

```
yes |bash script.sh
```

Or:

```
sudo apt update
yes |sudo apt update
yes |sudo apt upgrade
```